# int to float conversion in c#

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have a c# app that opens a file and parses binary data stored as ASCII Hex values. The problem I'm having is converting a floating-point number to a string. In this case, the number is 14.25, and the string is "41640000". I read the string out of the file to a local string.

```
String tmp = dlines[1].Substring( param_offset, param_size );
```

Since there is no float.Parse method that will accept an ascii hex string, I converted the string to an integer.

```
int itmp = int.Parse( tmp, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber );
```

Doing a cast only produces a very large number:

```
float ftmp = (float)itmp;
```

So I wrote a function to do the conversion. But it doesn't produce the right result.

```
        static float ToFloat( int i )
    {
        int sign, exp, frac, interim;
        float ffrac, pow;

        sign = (i < 0) ? -1:1;
        int pos = i * sign; // Convert to positive number.
        interim = pos >> 23;
        Console.WriteLine( "Int: 0x{0:x}, Pos: 0x{1:x}, Intr: {2}", i, pos, interim );
        exp  = interim - 127;
        frac = pos & 0x007fffff;
        ffrac = (frac / (float)8388608.0) + 1;
        pow = (float)Math.Pow( 2, exp );
        //string buf = String.Format( "0.0000", (((frac / 8388608.0) + 1.0) * Math.Pow( 2, exp )) );
        string buf = String.Format( "0.0000", ( ffrac * pow ) );
        float result = (float)(((frac / 8388608) + 1) * Math.Pow( 2, exp ));
        Console.WriteLine( "FloatValue: {0}, {1}, {2}, Exp: {3}, Pow: {4}", result.ToString ("0.0000" ), buf, ffrac, exp, pow );
        return result * sign;
    }
```

The output is:
    Int: 0x41640000, Pos: 0x41640000, Intr: 130,
    FloatValue: 8.0000, 0.0000, 1.78125, Exp: 3, Pow: 8

In the function above, how is it that this line:

```
string buf = String.Format( "0.0000", ( ffrac * pow ) );
```

produces a value of 0.0000 when ffrac = 1.78128, and pow = 8?

============================================================

This is what I tried:

```
        String stmp = tmp.Substring( index, 8 ); //, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber );
        byte[] barray = new byte[4];
        for ( byte b = 0, c=0; b < 4; b++, c += 2 )
        {
            barray[b]  = (byte)(FromHex( stmp[c] ) << 4);
            barray[b] |= FromHex( stmp[c+1] );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "String: {0}", stmp );
        Console.WriteLine( "Bytes: 0x{0:x} 0x{1:x} 0x{2:x} 0x{3:x}", barray[0], barray[1], barray[2], barray[3] );
        ftmp = BitConverter.ToSingle( barray, 0 );
        Console.WriteLine( "Float: {0}", ftmp.ToString( "0.0000" ) );
```

The output is:

```
String: 41640000
Bytes:  0x41 0x64 0x0 0x0
Float:  0.0000
```

Still doesn't work.

===============================================================
"Could you explain why 14.25 is represented as (hex) 41640000 = (decimal) 1097072640?"

The decimal value of 14.25 is represented in binary as 0x41640000 per the IEEE 754 spec.

Comment: Could you explain why 14.25 is represented as (hex) 41640000 = (decimal) 1097072640? It's not clear what the format is meant to be. If it's an IEEE754 representation, it would be better to just treat the binary data as bytes rather than as an integer. BitConverter is probably your friend at that point.

Comment: float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x41640000), 0);

Comment: In answer to your last question - your format string should be _"{0:0.0000}"_ or _"{0:F4}"_

Comment: I checked the docs for String.Format (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx). There's nothing there. Using "{0:F4}" produces output "0:F4".

Comment: Changing the format to {0:0.0000} worked.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate of "Convert Byte array into a float". I saw that post before posting. It didn't address/answer my question. And what's up with the -1 for my question?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to convert strings to floats:

```
float myFloat = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, startIndex);
```

you will first nned to convert the string into a byte array (similar to how you would create a null terminating byte string in C++). Then you can apply the command above to transform into a float (aka Single)

Comment: BitConverter did not work. The answer was to change the format string in my original question to {0:0.0000} as PaulF suggested.